# display full splash screen only the first time when upload the home web page

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can i display a splash screen only the first time that upload the home page, also i want the full screen mobile and desktop. I was trying this but it shows every time that upload the page, and not full screen, I mean full screen hide the web browser for 2 second during the splash screen animation, the animation is a svg animated file. This is the code that I was trying.

```js
    const splash = document.querySelector('.splash');
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (e)=>{
        setTimeout(()=>{
            splash.classList.add('display-none');
        }, 2000);
    })
```

```css
.splash{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100vh;
    background:#000000;
    z-index:999;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:90vh;
}
.splash.display-none{
    position:fixed;
    opacity:0;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100vh;
    background:#000000;
    z-index:-999;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:90vh;
    transition:all 0.5s;
}
@keyframes fadeIn{
    to{
        opacity:1;
    }
}
.fade-in{
    opacity:0;
    animation:fadeIn 1s ease-in forwards;
}
```

```html
<div class="splash">
    <p class="fade-in">
        <img src="https://2ndchance.mx/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/2ndchance-logo-animado-v1.0.0_animated-2.svg" alt="splash screen" width="200px"
    </p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When the user enter the page, you can show the animation and save a cookie, the next time check if the cookie exists, if not exists you can show the animation

Here is an example on  mozilla documentation:

```
function doOnce() {
  if (!document.cookie.split('; ').find(row => row.startsWith('doSomethingOnlyOnce'))) {
    // Note that we are setting `SameSite=None;` in this example because the example
    // needs to work cross-origin.
    // It is more common not to set the `SameSite` attribute, which results in the default,
    // and more secure, value of `SameSite=Lax;`
    document.cookie = "doSomethingOnlyOnce=true; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT; SameSite=None; Secure";

    const output = document.getElementById('do-once')
    output.textContent = '> Do something here!'
  }
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie#example_3_do_something_only_once

Answer (score 0):

`localStorage` is an easier way. localStorage can be stored with just one value in your case, whether it may be `true` or `false` in your situation.

By default, when a user hasn't visited the site yet, the localStorage would be undefined, which would mean the user obviously never visited the site before (or at-least very recently cleared their browsing data.)

Which means upon the user's first site visit to the site the storage would be updated to  `localStorage.seenScreen = true`

Then simply use an if statement to check if the value is `false` or `undefined` or `true`. If false, display splash screen, if true, dont display.

```
var seenSplash = localStorage.seenScreen

seenSplash ? showScreen() : console.log('Do not show screen')
```

You can find more information at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage